# Gradle flyway script to update multiple databases

Tags: gradle, flyway

I have a Gradle script which uses the flyway plugin to create some database tables, and now I need to update the script so that it can work with 2 separate sets of flyway scripts, each of which updates a separate database.

In the single-database version of the script I simply do this:

```
flyway {
    url = 'jdbc:edb://localhost:5432/mydb'
    schemas = ['my_schema']
    user = 'my_user'
    password = 'my_pass'
    locations = ['filesystem:src/main/resources/db/flyway/my_db']
}
```

I've been experimenting with declaring a new task to run the scripts for the second db:

```
task flywayMigrate2 << {
    ext {
        flyway {
            url = 'jdbc:edb://localhost:5432/mydb2'
            schemas = ['my_schema2']
            user = 'my_user2'
            password = 'my_pass2'
            locations = ['filesystem:src/main/resources/db/flyway/my_db2']
        }
    }    
}

flywayMigrate2.finalizedBy flywayMigrate
```

My Gradle skills are poor, but I know this isn't the right way to do it - my understanding is that the `ext` block overwrites the original flyway configuration, so if I wanted to run `flywayMigrate` after `flywayMigrate2` it would continue to use the second set of config values rather than reverting to the original set.

I can't be the first person to need to do this, but I'm struggling to find a decent approach, can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `flyway { ... }` extension object is for configuring properties which are common to all flyway tasks. Each task also has properties which can be configured, my guess is that task level properties override properties configured on the `flyway { ... }` extension object.

I think you'd just configure two [FlywayMigrateTask](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/master/flyway-gradle-plugin/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/gradle/task/FlywayMigrateTask.java) instances in your build.gradle

```
import org.flywaydb.gradle.task.*

task migrate1(type: FlywayMigrateTask) {
    url = 'jdbc:edb://localhost:5432/mydb1'
    user = 'user1'
    locations = ['filesystem:src/main/flyway/db1/migration']
    // etc
}

task migrate2(type: FlywayMigrateTask) {
    url = 'jdbc:edb://localhost:5432/mydb2'
    user = 'user2'
    locations = ['filesystem:src/main/flyway/db2/migration']
    // etc
}
```

See also [AbstractFlywayTask.java](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/master/flyway-gradle-plugin/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/gradle/task/AbstractFlywayTask.java)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you have to define another Gradle task in order to introduce a second Flyway configuration.

According to the [documentation](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/gradle/) you simply can overwrite either using Gradle properties

```
gradle -Pflyway.user=myUsr -Pflyway.schemas=schema1,schema2 -Pflyway.placeholders.keyABC=valXYZ
```

or system properties

```
gradle -Dflyway.user=myUser -Dflyway.schemas=schema1,schema2 -Dflyway.placeholders.keyABC=valueXYZ
```

or providing an external Flyway config

```
gradle -Dflyway.configFiles=path/to/myAlternativeConfig.conf flywayMigrate
```

The Flyway Gradle plugin follows the following configuration order:

1. System properties
2. Environment variables
3. Custom config files
4. Gradle properties
5. Flyway configuration section in build.gradle
6. `<user-home>/flyway.conf`
7. Flyway Gradle plugin defaults

Alternatively you could introduce a new task that overwrites the Gradle properties of Flyway.

```
task migrate2(FlywayMigrateTask) {

   project.ext['flyway.user']='myUsr'
   project.ext['flyway.password']='mySecretPwd'
   project.ext['flyway.schemas']='schema1,schema2,schema3'
   project.ext['flyway.placeholders.keyABC']='valueXYZ'
   project.ext['flyway.placeholders.otherplaceholder']='value123'

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I need the flyway configuration values to be contained inside the build script, rather than passed in on the command line. I think your project.ext example is just doing the same thing as my flywayMigrate2 task - ie overwriting global values which will stick around after the task completes